# Snow Leopard install Ruby on Rails (with MySQL)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, osx-snow-leopard, installation

I've done a clean re-install of OS X Snow Leopard, so there's nothing on my system at all.

I've installed Xcode and I'm ready to install Rails.

However, my system is a MacBook (MacBook2,1) and apparently it doesn't support 64-bit by default. Apple is going to add this at a later date.

How would I go about installing Rails? Do I go about it the normal way?

How about MySQL, do I need the 64-bit binary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly install the 64-bit packages. They will be able to access the memory space and every advantage of running with 64bits. The only thing that won't boot in 64bit is the Kernel, but it's not something to be worrying about for the moment.

Check out the Hivelogic's guide for installing MySQL, Rails and Ruby on Snow Leopard:

[MySQL](http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-mysql-on-snow-leopard/)
[Git](http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-git-on-snow-leopard/)
[Ruby, Rails](http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-ruby-rubygems-and-rails-on-snow-leopard/)

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time (maybe always, I'm not really sure) you can run binaries compiled for 32 bit even if your system is 64 bit. They just won't have any benefits of 64 bit (either storing bigger things or processing stuff faster).

If your macbook is a recent one it has 64 bit support (Core **2** Duo processor), if it is an older version (Core Duo) it is 32 bit. You can determine the processor type by checking 'About this Mac' in the Apple menu.

Comment: my Macbook is the latest plastic ones (MacBook2,1) 2GHZ Core 2 Duo. Would you recomend installing the 64bit binaries or the 32 bit ones?

Comment: Try the 64 bit ones, but if they are not available you should be able to use the 32 bit version.

Comment: I have one of the 2007 White Macbooks and the 64bit binaries work pretty well (as well as the gems)

Answer (score 1):

Your MacBook does support 64bit, but it cannot boot in 64bit mode. You should be able to install 64bit binary packages just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely install the 64-bit binory packages such as mysql.